# Ultilizing different Bootstrap form classes with bootstrap-sass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

How can I select different Bootstrap form class for forms with bootstrap-sass -gem?
Righ now I'm creating forms for user signup and login, and liked to utilize .form-inline class instead of the default .form-horizontal.

The code in view looks like this:

```
<%= form_for(@user, :html => {:class '.form-inline'}) do |f| %>
<div><%= f.label :email %><br />
<%= f.email_field :email %></div>

<div><%= f.label :password %><br />
<%= f.password_field :password %></div>

<% if devise_mapping.rememberable? -%>
<div><%= f.check_box :remember_me %> <%= f.label :remember_me %></div>
<% end -%>

<div><%= f.submit "Sign in" %></div>
<% end %>
```

This seems to generate html with right .form-inline class as the produced html looks like following, but the form is still formatted as .form-horizontal.

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/users" class="form-inline" id="new_user" method="post">
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Twitter bootstrap required specific html structure for forms, take a closer look at examples at http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/base-css.html#forms. Instead of building forms by hand I advise you to use simple_form gem, which can build forms with proper markup for twitter bootstrap: https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form.

Answer (score 0):

perhaps you're looking at it in a small device or window? 
bootstrap says:
"This only applies to forms within viewports that are at least 768px wide."